# Using superposition to reduce a complex solution

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a solution to under-damped harmonic oscillation:
$$x = e^{-(\frac{\beta}{2})t}[cos(\gamma t) \pm i sin(\gamma t)]$$

This is the correct reduction according to [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnderdampedSimpleHarmonicMotion.html) (10)
$$ x_1 =e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} t} cos(\gamma t)$$
$$ x_1 =e^{-\frac{\beta}{2} t} sin(\gamma t)$$

According to the article, you magically drop the i because the real and imaginary parts separately satisfy the ODE. I don't understand this. I am looking for clarification on why you can just drop the i out of the equation here.

My attempt at it went like this:

I see two solutions to the original differential equation:
$$x = e^{-(\frac{\beta}{2})t}[cos(\gamma t) + i sin(\gamma t)]$$
and
$$x = e^{-(\frac{\beta}{2})t}[cos(\gamma t) - i sin(\gamma t)]$$

Because it is a linear, homogeneous differential equation, I thought that you could use the superposition principle to additively combine separate solutions (the two above) to arrive at another valid solution to the equation. i.e
$$ 2 e^{-\frac{\beta}{2}t}cos(\gamma t) $$

Am I way off in how I am trying to use the superposition principle? How did they get rid of that i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your constant. The superposition principal means that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions, then for any constants $a,b$; $x = a x_1 + b x_2$ is also a solution.

So if you write
$$ x_1 = e^{-(\beta + i\gamma)t},\qquad x_2 = e^{-(\beta - i\gamma)t},$$
then
$$x = ae^{-(\beta + i\gamma)t} + be^{-(\beta - i\gamma)t}.$$
But since $x$ is real, the first term must be the complex conjugate of the second term, so that the imaginary parts cancel. This means that $a=b^*$, which gets rid of all those pesky $i$'s when you expand it all out.